# Use different serializer depending on the authentication method in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I'm trying to implement a user profile in django rest framework.

Users should be able to request the profile of other users; however, since profiles contain sensitive information, I want to limit the information returned to non-owners and non-authenticated users when they request a profile.

I'm looking for a test that I can run inside my view methods that will determine which serializer to use for that request.

How can I do this?

```
# models.py
class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='profile')
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # dob is sensitive and should be protected...
    dob = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

My serializers would look like this:

```
# serializers.py
# Only for the owner...
class ProfileOwnerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.id')
    first_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.first_name')
    last_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.last_name')

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = (
            'url',
            'id',
            'dob',     #sensitive
            'user',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',   #sensitive
        )

#For logged in users...
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.id')
    first_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.first_name')

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = (
            'url',
            'id',
            'bio',
            'user',
            'first_name',
        )

#For everyone else...
class NonAuthProfileSerializer:
    ...
```

And I would try to distinguish between them here...

```
# views.py
class ProfileDetail(APIView):
    """
    Retrieve a profile instance.
    """

    # Can't user permission_classes bc I want to cater to different classes...

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return Profile.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Profile.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        profile = self.get_object(pk)
        # is_owner = ???
        # is_authenticated = ???

        # Define the serializer to be ProfileSerializer, ProfileOwnerSerializer, etc.
        serializer = CorrectSerializer(
            profile,
            context={"request": request},
        )
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I don't think it'd be too hard to check if the request was sent by the owner, since I can just cross-reference the profile id.

However, how would I check whether the user was logged in or not? I've tried looking at `request.user.auth` in the view method, but that seems to be `None` whether or not the request is logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be checking with `request.user.is_authenticated()`. To fill in the blanks:

```
is_owner = profile.user == request.user
is_authenticated = request.user.is_authenticated()
```